# How do you test a custom dataset in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, torch

I've been following tutorials in Pytorch that use datasets from Pytorch that allow you to enable whether you'd like to train using the data or not... But now I'm using a .csv and a custom dataset.

```py
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, n_inp):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(root)
        self.data = self.df.to_numpy()
        self.x , self.y = (torch.from_numpy(self.data[:,:n_inp]),
                           torch.from_numpy(self.data[:,n_inp:]))
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x[idx, :], self.y[idx,:]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

How can I tell Pytorch not to train my test_dataset so I can use it as a reference of how accurate my model is?

```py
train_dataset = MyDataset("heart.csv", input_size)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle =True)
test_dataset = MyDataset("heart.csv", input_size)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle =True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pytorch, a custom dataset inherits the class `Dataset`. Mainly it contains two methods `__len__()` is to specify the length of your dataset object to iterate over and `__getitem__()` to return a batch of data at a time.

Once the dataloader objects are initialized (`train_loader` and `test_loader` as specified in your code), you need to write a train loop and a test loop.

```
def train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, dataloader):
    model.train()
    for i, (input, gt) in enumerate(dataloader):
        if params.use_gpu: #(If training using GPU)
            input, gt = input.cuda(non_blocking = True), gt.cuda(non_blocking = True)
        predicted = model(input)
        loss = loss_fn(predicted, gt)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

and your test loop should be:

```
def test(model,loss_fn, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    for i, (input, gt) in enumerate(dataloader):
        if params.use_gpu: #(If training using GPU)
            input, gt = input.cuda(non_blocking = True), gt.cuda(non_blocking = True)
        predicted = model(input)
        loss     = loss_fn(predicted, gt)
```

In additional you can use metrics dictionary to log your predicted, loss, epochs etc,. The main difference between training and test loop is that we exclude back propagation (`zero_grad(), backward(), step()`) in inference stage.

Finally,

```
for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    train(model, optimizer, loss_fn, train_loader)
    test(model, loss_fn, test_loader)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to note when you're testing in pytorch:

1. Put your model into evaluation mode so that things like dropout and batch normalization aren't in training mode: `model.eval()`
2. Put a wrapper around your testing code to avoid the computation of gradients (saving memory and time): `with torch.no_grad():`
3. Normalise or standardise your data according to your training set only. This is important for min/max normalisation or z-score standardisation so that the model accurately reflects test performance.

Other than that, what you've written looks pretty fine to me, as you're not applying any transforms to your data (for example, image flipping or gaussian noise injections). To show what code should look like in test mode, see below:

```
for e in range(num_epochs):
    for B, (dat, label) in enumerate(train_loader):
         #transforms here
         opt.zero_grad()
         out = model(dat.to(device))
         loss = criterion(out)
         loss.backward()
         opt.step()
    with torch.no_grad():
         model.eval()
         global_corr = 0
         for B, (dat,label) in enumerate(test_loader):
             out = model(dat.to(device))
             # get batch eval metrics here!
```