# How to transfer data for train pre-trained model with pytorch?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I want to classify images using a pretrained model **ResNet50** with **Pytorch**. I am faced with the problem of transferring data from the dataset to the model.

As far as I understood, it is necessary to transfer images for training in a tensor with the following dimension: (N, 4, 512,512), where N is the number of images, 4 is the number of channels, and 512 is the width and height of the picture. And also you need to pass "targets" as an array. Now I have a **Pandas DataFrame** with columns "Image", "Label". In the column "Images" I have a list of dimensions (512, 512, 4).
I tried writing data to an array, but it takes too long and takes up a lot of memory. Is there some other way to do this? **So, my question is "How can I transfer data into model?"**

This is part of my database:

| Number | Image | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0...` | 0 |
| 1 | `[[[4, 3, 0, 18], [82, 0, 0, 27], [11, 4, 0, 20...` | 14 |
| 2 | `[[[2, 2, 0, 0], [1, 5, 0, 1], [0, 5, 0, 0], [2...` | 14 |
| 3 | `[[[7, 1, 0, 24], [31, 0, 0, 14], [23, 3, 0, 13...` | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I tried to do it in the following way:

```py
x_train = []
y_train = []
for data in range(N):
    x_train.append(train_df['Image'].iloc[data])
    y_train.append(train_df['Label'].iloc[data])
x_train = torch.tensor(x_train)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train)
y_train = y_train.view(-1)
x_train = x_train.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: what you mean is to load batches of data using dataloader for inference ?

Comment: @NiveshGadipudi, the problem is that I do not know how to properly load data into the neural network. My way takes too much memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67291566/9489465 have a look at this thread. if you are not clear, then i will post a detailed code of how to do

Comment: @NiveshGadipudi, thank you very much, I understood everything.